# html5-Video-Tag vs. Streaming Server

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

Thanks to html5 it's very easy to stream a video to the customer by just adding it to the page with the **-tag.**

Anyway lots of big services **(you-tube etc.)** are still using streaming servers and flash to stream videos.

What's the benefit of this technologies?

Does it make any performance difference or difference for users perception? How does **html5-video** handle many request at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the main benefits of flash are:

- Easy to add Ads
- Browser compatibility
- No need to support many different codecs

So if you need any of this you might choose Flash

Comment: DRM is also something HTML5 video only begins to tackle when flash has well-established option for that.